# Not able to extract data inside for loop in Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Below is the code , I was able to console returned data using a testvalue variable but not able to get the data if i use for loop? What could be the reason for this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
value =  document.getElementById('tweets')
function fetchUserData(){
    fetch('/list/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data)=> {
          testvalue = data['response'][1]
           console.log(testvalue)
           for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++)
           {
               console.log(i)
           }
        })
        }
        fetchUserData()
    </script>
```

Comment: post your `console.log(data)` response . as per your code `data['response']`  means `data` is a object not a Array. May be try with `i<Object.values(data).length`

Comment: console.log(data): {isUser: false, response: Array(2)}
isUser: false
response: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, content: "First tweet"}
1: {id: 2, content: "second tweet"}

Comment: try this `i<data['response'].length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
value =  document.getElementById('tweets')
function fetchUserData(){
    fetch('/list/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data)=> {
          testvalue = data['response'][1]
           console.log(testvalue)
           for(var i =0; i<data['response'].length; i++)
           {
               console.log(i)
           }
        })
        }
        fetchUserData()
    </script>
```